# Change navigator's user agent on Blackberry Webworks for OS 6 and OS 7

Tags: blackberry, user-agent, blackberry-webworks

I'm working on an app for Blackberry 6 and 7 using Webworks. I was wondering if it is possible to change the Navigator's user agent.

What I'd like to do is, add a string at the end. For instance:

> Default: "Mozilla/5.0 (BB7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/33.0.1750.149 Safari/537.36"   Mine: "Mozilla/5.0 (BB7)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.149
>   Safari/537.36 CustomText"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to modify your config.xml and add the rim:userAgent attribute  in your widget element.
You can find an explanation and example at
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v1_0/widget_element_834671_11.html

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets"
    version="2.0.0.0"
    id="sampleapp"
    rim:header="RIM-Widget:rim/widget"
    rim:userAgent="BlackBerry10/MyWebWorksApp">
```

Comment: I may be confused but isn't this only for Widgets? I need the whole app to work with a custom User Agent.

Comment: The widget is a standard element for packaged applications. See the W3C definition: http://www.w3.org/TR/widgets/. You can check an example for a standard BlackBerry config.xml at https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v2_0/modifying_your_config_file.html  . So in order to customise a BlackBerry cordova app you will need to use the "rim:" attributes.